# How can I use SVM or Logical Regression on polynomial class labels?

Tags: classification, svm, multi-class

I was told that SVM would return good results for my research task, but afaik SVMs and Logical regression work with binomial class labels.

How can I make them work with classes that have more than two possible values?

Comment: Are you speaking of regression (*i.e.* numerical predictions) or classification (*i.e.* categorical predictions)?

Comment: I have ten classes and I want unlabeled data to be labeled accordingly

Answer (score 3):

First, as a matter of terminology, what you're actually referring to is ["multiclass" or "multinomial" classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification), not "polynomial" classification

One common technique for extending classification methods that work on binary labels to the multiclass setting is called "one-vs-rest"/"one-vs-all". Essentially, you turn your original problem - of predicting the correct class out of $K$ classes - into $K$ problems, where, in each problem, you predict the probability that your example belongs to the $i$th class. Then, you simply assign the example to the class with the largest probability. There are problems with this approach, some of which are discussed in the Wikipedia article referenced above, and there are also more sophisticated techniques (that tend to be more computationally expensive) for doing multiclass classification.

From the operational point of view, multiclass classification is implemented for all classifiers in [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html), including SVMs and logistic regression. There is even a module, [`sklearn.multiclass`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multiclass), that helps you implement *custom* strategies for multiclass classification if the ones already implemented are inadequate for your particular problem.